# using c# remove duplicate html span elements

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack, anglesharp

I have to convert word to html which I'm doing with Aspose and that is working well.  The problem is that it is producing some redundant elements which I think is due to the way the text is store in word.

For example in my word document the text below appears:

AUTHORIZATION FOR RELEASE

When converted to html it becomes:

```
<span style="font-size:9pt">A</span>
<span style="font-size:9pt">UTHORIZATION FOR R</span>
<span style="font-size:9pt">ELEASE</span>
```

I'm using C# and would like a way to remove the redundant span elements.  I'm thinking either AngleSharp or html-agility-pack should be able to do this but I'm not sure this is the best way?

Comment: It's not clear what you are calling *redundant element*. In the example above, it does not look like any of your span elements are redundant. If you want to get rid of the html created and just grab the text, you can refer to `[these span elements parent].InnerText`. All the text converted from word into your html - are being placed in span tags that look exactly like these ?

Comment: What I meant is that I would like the html to look like the following:    <span style="font-size:9pt">AUTHORIZATION FOR RELEASE</span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I wound up doing is iterating over all the elements and when adjacent span elements were detected I concatenated the text together. Here is some code if others run into this issue.  Note code could use some cleanup.

```
static void CombineRedundantSpans(IElement parent)
{
  if (parent != null)
  {               
    if (parent.Children.Length > 1)
    {
      var children = parent.Children.ToArray();
      var previousSibling = children[0];
      for (int i = 1; i < children.Length; i++)
      {
        var current = children[i];
        if (previousSibling is IHtmlSpanElement && current is IHtmlSpanElement)
        {
          if (IsSpanMatch((IHtmlSpanElement)previousSibling, (IHtmlSpanElement)current))
          {
              previousSibling.TextContent = previousSibling.TextContent + current.TextContent;
              current.Remove();
           }
           else
             previousSibling = current;
         }
         else
           previousSibling = current;
       }
     }
     foreach(var child in parent.Children)
     {
       CombineRedundantSpans(child);
     }
   }
}
static bool IsSpanMatch(IHtmlSpanElement first, IHtmlSpanElement second)
{
  if (first.ChildElementCount < 2 && first.Attributes.Length == second.Attributes.Length)
  {
    foreach (var a in first.Attributes)
    {
      if (second.Attributes.Count(t => t.Equals(a)) == 0)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```